# why did not logout after user delete from the account in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

In My laravel application I have option to user to delete there accounts.

userController

```
public function destroy($id)
{
        $users = User::findOrFail($id);
        $users->delete();
        Auth::logout();
        return Auth::logout();
}
```

this is delete button from blade file,

```
<a href="{{url('users')}}/{{$use->id}}" class="editInline" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this Collaborator?')"><i clas
                      s="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete</a>
```

and route

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@destroy',
]);
```

but after user delete, My system did not reditect home directory (logout). it is stop with following url in localhost

```
http://localhost:8000/users/5
```

but I need redirect my system to the home or login page. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redirect the user

```
public function destroy($id)
{
        $users = User::findOrFail($id);
        $users->delete();
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->to('/login');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify your return value in your destroy method(`public function destroy($id){}`) and change the return value to redirect as shown below:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    ...
    return redirect()->to('/home');
}
```

Now after session destroyed your user will be redirected to **home page**.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the`redirectTo` method of `LoginController` or `$ redirectTo`property